# What to do about disingenuous edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731690/fan-control-of-my-samsung-chronos-7) has an edit pending review, by the OP, to change the operating system and tag from ElementaryOS to Ubuntu 15.04. I'm assuming the OP has done this so he'll get an answer, despite EOS being off topic (and 15.04 also being EOL).

I wasn't sure how to review his edit, on the one hand I don't believe he's switched OS overnight, but on the other the edit wasn't worthy of rejection based on any of the reject reasons. I was also influenced by the prospect that it may not be an OS specific problem and that it's nice to try to help (especially new users).

I ended up skipping the edit review as I was just not sure. What should I have done?

Comment: Give em the befit of the doubt. I have Debian8, and Ubuntu comprising all my systems, and sometimes I get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the edit they made one massive mistake anyway, they change EOS for 15.04, so, it is still off topic,

I would reject and leave a comment for the OP, comment something like

"Please don't just change the version, we are aware you are using EOS a comment was left directing you to the EOS stack exchange but here it is again https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/, in-spite of your edit you STILL changed it to a version we do not support, 15.04, so your question is still off topic and will remain closed"

This is exactly what I did do and the edit is now completely rejected.

That edit is rubbish anyway and the OP did not even bother to post at EOS stackexchange or check what we support, don't let it bother you, this will never be reopened.

If they try to edit again, go to chat and tag a mod or flag for them to come and delete the question permanently (if they can).

Answer (score 1):

A mod will be able to determine whether the two accounts share the same IP and if that's the case merge the two accounts, but until proven true that the two accounts are owned by the same user the edit should be rejected as "Clearly conflicts with author's intent".

On whether to believe the user or not, if a legit edit (from the merged account in case of a merge or from the account from which the question was originally posted otherwise) will go through at some point, that will be up to the Reopen Votes reviewers.

Comment: True, I assumed that the same username meant the same user, but that's not always the case!

Comment: @Arronical That being said, I'll eat my hat if it turns out the two accounts are owned by different users. They share the same username and were created one within one day from the other, and one just edited the other's question; they either lost access to the first one or who knows what. It's just that such a radical edit is not acceptable until the two accounts being owned by the same user is proven true.